# unable to display the env var in my String

Tags: powershell, variables, environment

My script get a String value from another process like this :

```
PS C:\Users\Roger> echo $path
${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\Google
```

But

```
PS C:\Users\Roger> echo "${env:LOCALAPPDATA}"
C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Google
```

Is there a Powershell function I can apply to my variable path to get the environment variable correctly ?

Comment: How do you assign the value to to the var `$path` ? If this way `$Path = '${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\Google'` change the single to double quotes.

Comment: I received the value encoded and when it was decoded as a String it did not recognized the environment variable